# Как во Flutter создать поле для ввода числа

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-ui

Нужно поле ввода при переходе на которое открывалась бы цифровая клавиатура и  в которое можно было ббы вводить только цифры.
Позволяют ли это сделать Material виджеты?
Ряд обсуждений на github'е подтверждают, что Flutter поддерживает такую возможность.

Как это можно реализовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все просто.
Все данные функции поддерживает обычный `TextField`

Для того, чтобы при переходе на данное поле отображалась цифровая клавиатура необходимо указать тип клавиатуры:

```dart
keyboardType: TextInputType.number
```

Однако, это не накладывает никаких ограничений на содержимое поля и это не спасет Вас от вставленных пользователем (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> / <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>) символов, символов установленных программным путем и пр.

Для этого необходимо установить фильтр на вводимые данные.

```dart
inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
    FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly // С таким фильтром могут быть введены только числа
]
```

В итоге это поле можно объявить так:

```dart
new TextField(
    decoration: new InputDecoration(labelText: "Введите Ваше число"),
    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
    inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
        FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly // С таким фильтром могут быть введены только числа
    ],
),
```

#### Рабочий пример

main.dart

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return new MaterialApp(
      home: new HomePage(),
      theme: new ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.blue),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return new HomePageState();
  }
}

class HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: new Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(40.0),
          child: new Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          new TextField(
            decoration: new InputDecoration(labelText: "Введите Ваше число"),
            keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
            inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
    FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly // С таким фильтром могут быть введены только числа
],
          ),
        ],
      )),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]